# Word to describe architectural features that are only aesthetic

Tags: single-word-requests

I think there are two different words to describe architectural features that are only for aesthetic purposes.  One that I think begins with an "n" and one that begins with a "g".

The usage would be: "That building is so boring, it is a plain brick wall with no >insert word<".

Or: "this old building is very interesting as there's a lot of >insert word<.  Look at all the intricate brick work, inlaid with a different stone, and use of pillars, steps, etc"

I have tried searching dictionaries but not been successful yet.  Have searched for the title of this post and for "architectural words beginning with g".

Comment: Are you looking for gargoyle?

Comment: Want ornamentation?

Comment: Thanks @YosefBaskin .  I think there's a more specific word or two!) but that's definitely a good start.

Comment: You can look through the [de Ferranti](https://deferranti.com/index.php/glossary/letter/b) glossary of architectural terms. If you don't find these terms there, I'm afraid you could be instigating a wild goose chase here. Grotesques is a gross hyponym and garniture and gilding gross hypernyms, and as such  off-topic.

Comment: I don't think *aesthetic* is what you mean. For example, columns that are structural may be more or less aesthetically pleasing in design.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of words that fit your description - ornamentation, decoration, adornment, and their synonyms.

If you are in North America the word beginnging with G may be:

> [Gingerbread](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gingerbread): lavish or superfluous decoration, especially in architecture